# Trouble freeing memory

Tags: arrays, malloc, free

I have a struc of 3 void*:

```
typedef struct ck{

void * arg1;
void * arg2;
void * arg3;


} argCookie;
```

later on I instanciate argCookie:

```
argCookie myCookie;
```

and then I assing some values to it's arguments:

```
 unsigned long size;
//give a value to size
unsigned short array[size];
//fill the array

myCookie.arg1=malloc(sizeof(size));
myCookie.arg2=malloc(sizeof(array));
memcpy(myCookie.arg1,&size,sizeof(size));
memcpy(myCookie.arg2,array,sizeof(array));
```

so far so good, I can now acess array and size from my struct, no problem. The problem occurs when I try to free the memory I've allocated:

```
free(myCookie.arg1);
free(myCookie.arg2);//something goes bad when this line of code is executed don't know why
free(myCookie.arg3);
myCookie.arg1=NULL;
myCookie.arg2=NULL;
myCookie.arg3=NULL;
```

when the line " free(myCookie.arg2);" is executed I get the following message:

"panic: Assertion "(char *) NextSlot(prev) <= p" failed, file "/usr/src/lib/libc/ansi/malloc.c", line 252

syslib:panic.c: stacktrace: 0x468b 0x53b4 0x975a 0x2a33 0x2582 0x100a"

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

Thank you

Comment: Is it pseudocode or did you use a variable length array, in which case sizeof(array) returns the number of element and not its size in byte

Comment: well I did use sizeof(array) but as long as I know sizeof(array) will return the number of bites of array and not the number of elements...

Comment: What happens if you free them in reverse order?  I.e. `free(myCookie.arg3);` first, followed by `free(myCookie.arg2);` then
    `free(myCookie.arg1);`.

Answer (score 0):

free(myCookie.arg1) is cleaning the memory allocated to the entire struct.

I think you should just free the whole thing:

```
free(myCookie);
```

Comment: To me it doesn't seem to make sense. I've never used malloc on myCookie so there is no reason to free it, or is it? btw I can free myCookie.arg1 with no problem... the problem is only with arg2...

Comment: Oh, actually I was wrong.  I think your problem is that you haven't given a value to size. So array[size] is of unknown length.

Comment: I have given a value to it. and with arg1 everything is perfectly fine I can read the value and it's correct...the problem happens when I try to free arg2... btw I can acess arg2 and it's value is correct....

Comment: myCookie.arg2=malloc(sizeof(array)+1);  Possible null-terminator issue?  Sorry, now I'm just shooting blanks ;p

Answer (score 0):

I think that when since you have arg1 allocated a size of 'size' and arg2 allocated a size of 'array', that should correspond to the data type of these structure members. 
So,
void * arg1;

should be :

unsigned long * arg1;

Similarly, modify arg2 and arg3.